# How do i save an image in core data then retrieve it? Using swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I don't want to use `NSUserDefaults`, so how do I save an image in core data then retrieve it?

My image is in this variable.

```
var image:UIIMage = image1
```

Can you please give me some sample code to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995955/saving-picked-image-to-coredata/27996685#27996685

Answer (score 2):

UIImage -> NSData

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); or  UIImageJpegRepresentation(image)
```

NSData -> UIImage

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `UIImage` into `NSData` and save as the entity's attribute with the type `Binary Data`

Answer (score 0):

this question is already answered  by stack-overflow refer this

[How to store an image in core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685812/how-to-store-an-image-in-core-data)