# Performance for Core Data and UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimage, nsdata

I have an image in Core Data. It has to be saved as NSData, and I have a computed property to get and set the image based on the Core Data property `imageData`:

```
var image: UIImage? {
    get {
        if let imageData = imageData {
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    set {
        if let image = image {
            imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        } else {
            imageData = nil
        }
    }
}
```

However, I believe that this code will convert between `UIImage` and `NSData` every time the image is fetched, which can be very often since this data is used to populate a `UITableViewCell`. Is this true, or is Xcode smart enough to cache computed properties in some way? Also, is this the recommended way of fetching images from Core Data, or is it recommended to fetch it once and save it to a new property like this (unsure if this code is correct):

```
lazy var image: UIImage? = {
        if let imageData = imageData {
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
}()
```

The downside of the last one the way I see it is that it would be possible to change `imageData` without `image` being updated. I'm also not sure if I can just use `didSet` in the latter version to update Core Data.

Comment: [look at this git repo](https://github.com/romainmenke/SimpleCam) It displays images from CoreData in a table. It is asynchronous and does not fetch the images in the cell, but in a separate method. [how to : images & coredata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995955/saving-picked-image-to-coredata/27996685#27996685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `imageData` is a property of the entity description,

- The managed object context will cache `imageData`.
- The `image` will not be cached, and will be recomputed every time.

If you're going to store images in Core Data, the right approach is simpler than you're making it. `UIImage` conforms to `NSCoding`, which means you can just create an `image` attribute with the Core Data "transformable" type. Core Data will then automatically invoke `NSCoding` methods to convert to/from `UIImage` and you don't need any of the code in your question. You just read/write your `UIImage`.

If you're going to store images in Core Data, using **any** scheme, make sure that the images aren't too large. Core Data can handle them but you may find that the image data gets loaded when you don't expect. For example, if you're only using other non-image attributes of a managed object, but the image data gets loaded anyway.

Comment: Also, mark the image attribute with "External Storage" in the model editor if the images are large.

Comment: @Mundi unfortunately that's (still!) not an option for transformable attributes.

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out! I guess another solution worth being pointed out is then to use `NSData` as the property type, choose "External Storage" and write a convenience method to retrieve the image. This would be very close to OP's solution.

Comment: Thank you. This solution sounds great, but I fail at implementing this. When I set my image property to transformable in Core Data and generate an `NSManagedObject`, it gets the type `NSObject?`. If I just assign `myImageView.image = myTransformableProperty`, I obviously get an error message saying that I cannot assign a value of type `NSObject?` to type `UIImage?`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I changed NSObject? to UIImage? and everything works!