# How To Add A Image In CoreData And How to Save The Image In CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

How to add an image in core data? The image type what that I have selected. And how to save the core data image. How can I add a image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27996685/8306054 Have you refered this.?

Comment: And if your purpose is just to save the image. It would be good to save it in Document directory and store its path or name to core data so that you can fetch them

Comment: i have save image and fetch the image in table view.

Comment: so u can use the code to save the image in document directory and save its path to  core data and then show it in table view.From where are you getting images.? You are selecting that from image picker.?

Comment: ok Thank you I will try it now

Comment: if u want i can make code for you. But please conform what is your image source.? I mean from image picker or any other.?

Comment: i have use the below code is possible to save the image and data but image i have selected binary data. But it shows the no data to convert ui image,   the below code i have tried                                        CoreDataHandler.saveObject(fName: fname.text!, lName: lname.text!, mobilenumber: mobileNumber.text!, Age: age.text!, Dob: dob.text!,Image: image.UIImage)

Comment: You did not understand my question. My question is from where are you picking image to save.? Is that from Image picker or any other source like web server or any other.?

Comment: i have taken the ui image view i have given the outlet connection of imagePicker i have given Kindly please arrage the code fo me. like the image picking from gallery or camera captures.

Comment: ok i got you point. Wait lemme arrange one for you.

Comment: ok thank you for giving response to me

Comment: Please check the answer. If it works let me know

Comment: its Working Thank You..

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times on Stack Overflow. Please search for answers before posting a new question.

Comment: @BSuresh If it worked for you please approve my answer.

Comment: hiii Could please help me on How to create the calendar in tableview above the list of tableview with calendar all month dates and everything.Please help me on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:-** Save the image in Document Directory

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let newPath = path.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg") //Possibly you Can pass the dynamic name here
    // Save this name in core Data using you code as a String.
    let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    do {
        try jpgImageData!.write(to: newPath)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}}
```

**Step:-2:**  Fetch the Image back from the Document Directory and display index path row wise in table view cell.

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath          = paths.first
    {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("image.png") //Pass the image name fetched from core data here
        let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
        cell.imageView.image = image
}
```

This is simple and More convenient Method