# Saving a UIImageView in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uiimageview, save

I am currently making a notebook application for a school project in swift, however, I am unsure how to save the UIImageView as a record so I could open it up at a later time for further editing. I have attempted to use Core Data but have not found a way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

[This is the storyboard of the note writing screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxwJ9.png)

[After drawing a note as such, I want to be able to save that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F71Fu.png)

Comment: What did you already try? Do you have a `UIImage` with the note on it and you want to save it now?

Comment: You are being too vague. (1) You probably know that you don't save UIImageViews`, you save `UIImages` - their contents. But it's hard to know what you're asking. (2) That's because nobody - except you - knows your definition of "receive and edit". For instance, when I see someone building a "notebook" app I immediately think "text" or yes, CoreData, not images. Which is it? (3) But mostly, you haven't given us code, nor input and expected output, nor anything really specific. Could you detail things enough for us to be helpful?

Comment: Please can you share some code or a screenshot of the output?

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added screenshots of the output and the storyboard. To clarify, I want to save the note so that it can be edited at a later point in time, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

you have two option.

1. Store Image to Coredata Directly

[Saving Picked Image to CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995955/saving-picked-image-to-coredata)

2. save image to Document directory and Store that Url to Coredata

https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707