# how to save my image into a database using sqlite?

Tags: swift, database, xcode, sqlite

I am making an app where you can post an image and display it on another page. I want to save it to a database but I don't know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can save your image in document folder by using

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
    guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) ?? UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        return false
    }
    guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
        return false
    }
    do {
        try data.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent("fileName.png")!)
        return true
    } catch {   
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}
```

and you can get it your image with this method :

```
func getSavedImage(named: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent(named).path)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Core data** in swift to **save Image**. 
**Core Data** is an object graph and persistence framework provided by Apple in the macOS and iOS operating systems. 
By using Core data you can access sqlite database easily.

**To save image** in Sqlite Using Core Data **See** [saving-picked-image-to-coredata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995955/saving-picked-image-to-coredata)

Answer (score 0):

you save your image in device and save path of that image in Sqlite.

this link for how to save image in device [Saving image and then loading it in Swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344822/saving-image-and-then-loading-it-in-swift-ios)