# How to Store the online images and data for offline purpose

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services

I have to build an iPhone app that check for the net connectivity and whenever it get it has an online sync with a web service, it downloads X images and saves them into the device.

Then, in offline mode, I have to load the images in collectionview for that i have to store images somewhere.Same For data also

I am using .net webservice with json response.

I was thinking about the Core Data storage, is that possible? Maybe storing images in core data database will slow down the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to download and save each received image in the application directory, then you save in CoreData the path to those images.

```
// Save image to disk
    NSString *documentaryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Image.png",documentaryPath];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(YOUR_IMAGE)];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Retrieve the Image
- (NSData *) imageData {

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Image.png",docDir];

    NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];

    return dataImage;
}
```

And use like below.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Yes sure. Tell me what kind of help you want.

Comment: What if if i dont want the user to see that image or data folder...but it still be there in our own application  For Example if we put . extension in image folder user cant access through gallery @bhumica

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible,but not worthwhile.

As usually,we cache an image with follow steps:

1. Check whether we have load the image at the specific URL,if yes,go `step 2`,otherwise,go `step 3`
2. Load the image from file.
3. DownLoad the image,and save it to file.**you should give the image file a name  associated with its URL,so you can find it by the url next time**.

There is a tool can do bellow work well,you can try using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store images in core data in the form of Binary Data, here is an example of how to do it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687218/4813440)!
As far as speed is concerned core data will not slow down your app performance but it usually takes more space than sqlite, here's [a link](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/ios-data-storage-core-data-vs-sqlite/240168843?pgno=2)! that show comparison between core data and sqlite performance.