# How to pass UIImage with Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, segue

I have a main VC, which displays data added by a user, and a VC where the user inputs the data.

What I am trying to do is pass the image from the adding VC to the main VC.

Currently, I get the SIGABRT error when I press save, and the following error message:

> 2016-04-14 08:07:23.207 On The Go[27697:2680635] -[On_The_Go.Agenda setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf03063900
>   2016-04-14 08:07:23.212 On The Go[27697:2680635] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[On_The_Go.Agenda setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf03063900'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010442bd85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106897deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104434d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010437acfa ___forwarding_** + 970
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010437a8a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>       5   On The Go                           0x0000000103e97e11 _TFC9On_The_Go22AddTableViewController4savefCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 4897
>       6   On The Go                           0x0000000103e9842a _TToFC9On_The_Go22AddTableViewController4savefCSo15UIBarButtonItemT_ + 58
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010531da8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010572b067 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010531da8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000105490e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000105491143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
>       12  UIKit                               0x00000001054912be -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 706
>       13  UIKit                               0x0000000105490263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>       14  UIKit                               0x000000010539099f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>       15  UIKit                               0x00000001053916d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010533cdc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>       17  UIKit                               0x0000000105316553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104351301 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010434722c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043466e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043460f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109efbad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       23  UIKit                               0x000000010531bf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       24  On The Go                           0x0000000103e9b672 main + 114
>       25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010736492d start + 1
>       26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

My code is:

Main VC:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var content:[Agenda] = []
var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!
var searchController:UISearchController!
var searchResults:[Agenda] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agenda")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "subject", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            content = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [Agenda]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 76.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search items..."
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
        return content.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let agenda = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : content[indexPath.row]

    cell.subjectLabel.text = agenda.subject
    cell.deadlineLabel.text = agenda.deadline
    cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(data: agenda.image!)

    if agenda.urgent == true {
        cell.urgentImageView.image = UIImage(named: "urgent")
        cell.urgentImageView.image = cell.urgentImageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        cell.urgentImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 212.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 106.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        cell.urgentImageView.image = nil
    }

    cell.subjectLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.subjectLabel.numberOfLines = 999
    cell.deadlineLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.deadlineLabel.numberOfLines = 999

    cell.subjectLabel.sizeToFit()
    cell.deadlineLabel.sizeToFit()

    cell.subjectLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Share", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        let defaultText = "I've got to " + self.content[indexPath.row].subject
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

            let itemToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Agenda
            managedObjectContext.deleteObject(itemToDelete)

            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    })

    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 28.0/255.0, green: 165.0/255.0, blue: 253.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 202.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 203.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    return [deleteAction, shareAction]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if searchController.active {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        case .Delete:
            if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        case .Update:
            if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }

        default:
            tableView.reloadData()
    }

    content = controller.fetchedObjects as! [Agenda]
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    searchResults = content.filter({ (content:Agenda) -> Bool in
    let nameMatch = content.subject.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    let deadlineMatch = content.deadline.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return nameMatch != nil || deadlineMatch != nil
    })
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
}
```

Adding VC:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Table view data source

@IBOutlet var photoImageView:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var subjectTextField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var deadlineTextField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var yesButton:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var noButton:UIButton!

var urgent = true
var content:Agenda!
var imageName:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    title = "Add an item"

    photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    photoImageView.image = photoImageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    photoImageView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    if imageName == "cup" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 137.0/255.0, green: 72.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "transport" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    } else if imageName == "beach" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    } else if imageName == "weather" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "gear" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 106.0/255.0, green: 207.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "money" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 110.0/255.0, green: 110.0/255.0, blue: 110.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "technology-1" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    } else if imageName == "web" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 114.0/255.0, blue: 110.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "people" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 251.0/255.0, blue: 208.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "nature" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 110.0/255.0, green: 118.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "draw" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    } else if imageName == "technology" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 131.0/255.0, green: 249.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "screen" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 135.0/255.0, green: 134.0/255.0, blue: 135.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "shop" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 210.0/255.0, green: 120.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    } else if imageName == "arrow" {
        photoImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func save(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

    let subject = subjectTextField.text
    let deadline = deadlineTextField.text
    let icon = UIImage(named: imageName)

    if subject == "" || deadline == "" || icon == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Not all of the fields have been filled in. Please fill them in before proceeding.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }

    if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

        content = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Agenda", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Agenda
        content.subject = subject!
        content.deadline = deadline!
        content.urgent = urgent

        if let iconImage = photoImageView.image {
            content.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(iconImage)
        }

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func toggleUrgentButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender == yesButton {
        urgent = true
        yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        noButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    } else if sender == noButton {
        urgent = false
        yesButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        noButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToIcon(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}
}
```

My class (Agenda):

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Agenda:NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var subject:String
@NSManaged var deadline:String
@NSManaged var urgent:NSNumber?
@NSManaged var image:NSData?
}
```

The image gets chosen from another VC, but if you need that code, feel free to ask.

I want to get the image into the main VC's iconImageView.

Comment: It's a well know issue. It's hard to tell where is your issue exactly, because there is plenty of mentions of "agenda" or "image", where you are calling `setImage:` on a `Agenda` object (could be on the form `agendaObject.image =`. Which line exactly causes the crash? You can find it by putting break points...

Comment: Agenda doesn't have a property .image by the looks of it...

Comment: @Magoo Agenda is a class. I will add the code to the question.

Comment: @Larme Agenda is a class. I will add the code to the question.

Comment: @Larme Any more luck on this?

Answer (score 0):

OK so just to check. You're using the `Binary Data` option for `image` in the Core Data model right?

If so you can store an image if you also click allows external storage and use `agenda.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` or JPG instead of PNG for jpegs

[How to store an image in core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685812/how-to-store-an-image-in-core-data)