# Storing multiple images in swift data

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am currently working on a project that needs to allow users to store multiple images in swift data! I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this. below is my current model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class SwiftDataModel {
    // Session Data
    var record_type: WorkRecordType
    var amount: Int
    var nameOfSession: String
    var date: Date
    var canvas: Data
    var taps: Int
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var photo: Data?
    // Doc Scan Data
   
    // Event Data
    var subject_type: EventType
    var name_of_event: String
    var event_date: Date
    var is_notified: Bool
    
    init(amount: Int = 0, nameOfSession: String = "", Date: Date = .now, /*canvas: Data = Data(),*/ record_type: WorkRecordType = .dont_record, taps: Int = 0, name_of_event: String = "", event_date: Date = .now, subject_type: EventType = .other, is_notified: Bool = false) {
        // Session Data
        self.amount = amount
        self.nameOfSession = nameOfSession
        self.date = Date
        self.canvas = Data()
        self.record_type = record_type
        self.taps = taps
        // Event Data
        self.name_of_event = nameOfSession
        self.event_date = Date
        self.subject_type = subject_type
        self.is_notified = is_notified
        //Doc Scan Data
        
    }
}
```

I know how to store one image in swift data but I dont know how to store an array of images in swift data.

Comment: I think it would be better to just store the image location. Keep your data as light as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new model that holds the image data:

```
@Model class Photo {
    var id: UUID //optionally add some other fields if needed
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var photo: Data
    init(photo: Data) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.photo = photo
    }
}
```

And in `SwiftDataModel` you can add a `[Photo]` property  which will create a one to many relation between the 2 models.

Using `@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)` here will allow you to automatically remove the photos when deleting their parent.

```
@Model
class SwiftDataModel {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var photos: [Photo]
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Saving an array of `Data` in `SwiftDataModel` works but gives you the following warnings:

> CoreData: debug: PostSaveMaintenance: fileSize 28234392 greater than prune threshold
> CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [Data] as type?

```
@Attribute(.externalStorage) var photos: [Data]
```

Also, be aware of the up- and downsides of storing photos (and large data) this way, [see similar discussion in CoreData thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685812/how-to-store-an-image-in-core-data)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As far as I understand, it works similarly to the CoreData option of "allow external storage", which is mentioned in the linked discussion. Am I wrong?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-store-swiftdata-attributes-in-an-external-file
This article suggests otherwise. Generally, since "SwiftData uses the proven storage architecture of Core Data", many of the same considerations apply.

Comment: I just tried this solution and it works fine, one problem is of course if you want to access a specific image then a relationship is better. Another possible problem might be memory management but I didn’t test that. Anyway, a good solution for smaller images or other data blobs where it’s fine to load everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

[otaviokz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884744/otaviokz)'s answer makes sense to me.

Saving photo's Data in as external storage is completely transparent for a SwiftData user, except you can't use them in Predicates.

It's important to remember that Swift's `.externalStorage` attribute merely suggests to SwiftData something should be stored outside of the underlying SQLite, but it doesn't necessary honours that request.

One last thing I'd like to say is that you can add other attributes to an externally stored, such as Cloud Encryption:

```
@Attribute(.externalStorage, .allowsCloudEncryption) var avatar: Data
```

Answer (score 0):

[Joakin Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson), I'm not sure why you mention storing multiple images when your code has:

```
@Attribute(.externalStorage) var photo: Data?
```

I suppose you meant something like:

```
@Attribute(.externalStorage) var photos: [Data]?
```

According to [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/about), in his [article concerning your case](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-store-swiftdata-attributes-in-an-external-file), you can simply save your images as Data blobs and later access them via the `SwiftDataModel` parent you already have have in place:

```
@Model
class SwiftDataModel {
    // Session Data
    var record_type: WorkRecordType
    var amount: Int
    var nameOfSession: String
    var date: Date
    var canvas: Data
    var taps: Int
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var photos: [Data]?
    // Doc Scan Data
}
```

Just keep in mind you won't be able to use those images in Predicates.

> Third, for the most part all this is an implementation detail:
>
> ***whether the data is stored right inside the database or not doesn’t matter to us,*** because it’s loaded and saved the same as internal data.
>
> ***However, you cannot use externally stored properties inside predicates, because the external files aren’t visible to the underlying data store.***
>
> – if you see an error message like:
>
> ***[Foundation.__NSSwiftData _bytesPtrForStore]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x600000c74ae0 with userInfo of (null)***
>
> - chances are you might have fallen into this trap.

[image]