# Unable to take a photo and have it persist in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

Can someone please help with an `UIImagePickerController` function and a way to save? I have been able to take a photo and even have it show up in my `UIImageView`, but have yet to be able to keep it there, where as the text I'm working with has been saved.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var newKid: Kid? = nil
    var pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // MARK: - IBOutlet

    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if newKid != nil {
            nameText.text = newKid?.name
            ageText.text = newKid?.age
         // imageView.image = newKid?.image
        } 
    }

    // MARK: - IBAction

    @IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissVC()
    }

    @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if newKid != nil {
            editEntry()
        } else {
            newEntry()
        }
        dismissVC()
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = .Camera
        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Helper Functions

    func newEntry() {

        var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Kid", inManagedObjectContext: context!)

        let newKid = Kid(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newKid.name = nameText.text
        newKid.age = ageText.text
     // newKid.image = imageView.image
     // context?.save(nil)
        saveEntry()
        println(newKid)
        println("Object saved.")
        dismissVC()
    }

    func editEntry() {
        newKid?.name = nameText.text
        newKid?.age = ageText.text
        newKid?.image = imageView.image
    }

    func saveEntry() {
        var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        context?.save(nil)
    }

    func dismissVC() {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
    }

    @IBAction func useCamera(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {

                let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

                imagePicker.delegate = self
                imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

                self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
                    completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer that shows how to store and retrieve a UIImage from CoreData: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3844130/78496

Comment: This is a bit broad. What have you done so far to attempt to save the image?

Comment: Thank you chedabob, but I don't understand obj-c...a bit of a newbie.  rmaddy, image is stored as an NSManagedObject in my model class, but I can't seem to convert the image taken with image picker to an NSData object.  It's all really confusing.  I've commented the image section in the function newEntry because I was getting the NSDATA error.  And I thought the way you save it once is just context?.save(nil)....

Comment: As you can see, I'm still searching for a solution to this problem.  I don't think the question is too broad.  I understand how to take the photo, get it to show up in the UIImageview, I just can't get it to persist in Core Data.  I've read I need to convert it to NSData using a dictionary, but I am unsure as to how to complete this task.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any and all info is appreciated!!!!!!