# Swift: Save and Retrieve UIImage Into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to save the UIImage that I get from the UIImagePickerCollector into CoreData attribute "img" that is Binary Data type. I just try to save using following code.

```
let sampleimage = profileimg?.image
    var dataImage: Data? = nil
    if let aSampleimage = sampleimage {
        dataImage = aSampleimage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)
    }

    let imag = Data()

    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into: Constant.context!)

    newUser.setValue(self.txtName!.text, forKey: Constant.CDName)
    newUser.setValue(self.txtEmail!.text, forKey: Constant.CDEmail)
    newUser.setValue(self.txtPassword!.text, forKey: Constant.CDPassword)
    newUser.setValue(yourDate, forKey: Constant.CDDob)
    newUser.setValue(imag, forKey: Constant.CDImage)
```

When I try to run the it not showing any error. But I don't know image is save in CoreData OR not. How can I check it?

And when I try to assign the image into my table view cell it's show me following error. Please prove proper solution.

Comment: Binary Data is Data type, not UIImage, you can convert it to UIImage by `UIImage(data:)`

Comment: @Krunal - You are getting is NSData to UIImage conversion error. Try using UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0) presuming the image's scale is 1.

Comment: can you please provide me full code. Thanks

Comment: Please see answer section. Let me know if that works fine with you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and Retrieve of an UIImage on CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353172/save-and-retrieve-of-an-uiimage-on-coredata)

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should save image into document directory and save path into coredata.

Comment: @Cristik I can found any answer in swift. The answer is in Objective C. Please check and correct the vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `NSData` to `UIImage` conversion error. Try using 
`UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)` presuming the image's scale is 1.

For you code it could be something like :

```
if let imgData = obj.img {
    cell.listImg.image = UIImage(data:imgData, scale:1.0) //presuming the image's scale is 1
}
```

Other variation could be

```
if let imgData = obj.img {
    cell.listImg.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
}
```

Saving image, In the statement `newUser.setValue(imag, forKey: Constant.CDImage)`, you are using `imag`, however actual image is contained in `dataImage`. Please correct it

```
newUser.setValue(imag, forKey: Constant.CDImage)
```

to

```
newUser.setValue(dataImage, forKey: Constant.CDImage)
```

Also for the shared code snipped, I don't see any use of `let imag = Data()`, you can remove it if its not being used beyond the part of code you shared.

Comment: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
This error is showing. I think image is not save into CoreData correctly.

Comment: use Optional Chaining to avoid this error. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Where is optional chaining in updated answer ? Do you understand the difference between optional unwrapping and optional chaining ?

Comment: My Bad I mean optional unwrapping with if let. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: ok. the error is gone now but the image is still not showing. Can you please check and let me know that, Is that a correct way to save image into CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the image, you can set the field as Binary data and you have to convert and save to the core data

> UIImage to Data

```
if let img = image {
   let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img!)
}
```

and when you fetch

> Data to UIImage

```
if let img_data = data {
   let image = UIImage(data:img_data)
}
```

so like this you have to create the object of coredata entity and then you have to create field as binary data and save the data of UIImage and when you want to fetch then again need to convert from data to image and assign to your UIImageview.

Comment: awesome. Working very properly. Hit the vote button if you really enjoy thanks.

Comment: @Ronak - forced unwrapping of image!, can lead to fatal error in case when imge is nil. This is not suggested way of using optional.

Comment: @Rizwan Code updated